# Cauchy integral description

Tags: complex-analysis

If we have $z(t)=re^{it},  0\leq t \leq 2\pi $ and $r >0$,
How can we show an analytic description of the interior bounded by $\gamma$ which is a closed path, and show that it is star-shaped? Please help I don't know where to start.

Comment: Have you tried visualizing the curve? What does it look like? Is there a common name for it?

Comment: i could visualize a curve which is indeed a disk with origin 0 and radius r, but how do i do an "analytic description"? @whacka

Comment: what is $\gamma$ ???

Comment: And proving that itis star shaped is simply an argument of having 2 arbitrary points in the disk which can be connected.

Comment: @Arashium it is updated. it is a closed path.

Comment: So $\gamma$ is any closed path in $\Bbb C$, not necessarily a circle?

Comment: so the question is as: z(t)=... then prove ... about something else ($\gamma$) ?

Comment: @Arashium im just as confused as you are. i guess its just asking for an analytic description, and proving it is star shaped

Comment: @kobe perhaps, but given radius r>0 implies it is a disk.

Comment: Then you should say $\gamma$ is parametrized by $z(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\gamma$ is a circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin, the interior of $\gamma$ is the open disk of radius $r$ centered at the origin. Not only is $\text{int}(\gamma)$ star-shaped, but it's convex. For given any $z, w\in \text{int}(\gamma)$ and $s \in [0,1]$, $|(1 - s)z + sw| \le |(1 - s)z| + |sw| = (1 - s)|z| + s|w| < (1 - s)r + sr = r$. Thus $(1 - s)z + sw \in\text{int}(\gamma)$ for all $z, w \in \text{int}(\gamma)$ and $s \in [0,1]$. This shows that $\text{int}(\gamma)$ is convex, and in particular, star-shaped.

Comment: thanks. let me decipher that for a bit...